# Load a javascript function in html code

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I want to read the values of several div using the javascript method innerHTML and save them in variables. That is the javascript code:

```
function llegirdata()
{
    var spandies = document.getElementById('dies').innerHTML;
    var spanhores = document.getElementById('hores').innerHTML;
    var spanminuts = document.getElementById('minuts').innerHTML;
    var spansegons = document.getElementById('segons').innerHTML;
    console.log(spanhores);
 }
```

This code is in a script called temps.js. The html code is:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/temps.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="contenidor">

 <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
        <span id="dies">1</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Dies</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="hores">1</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hores</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="minuts">40</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minuts</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="segons">00</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Segons</div>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">
      llegirdata();     
    </script>
</body>
```

When I run the code in the browser the value of spanhores variable is not displayed in console. There is the error

Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

I know this error means that script is loaded before html code and the innerHTML method can't read the value of span id=hores. And this is what I don't understand, because I load the script after the html code is loaded.

I don't want to type javascript inside html file because I need to do more functions to calculate some values.

How can I display the value of the spanhores variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote? Good question, code provided, attempt at solving..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error consists in placing the script before your html code.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Function runs and tries to go for those values contained in the html, but at that point are not defined. Easily solved like this:

```
<body>
<div class="contenidor">

 <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
        <span id="dies">1</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Dies</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="hores">1</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hores</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="minuts">40</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minuts</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="segons">00</span>
        <div class="smalltext">Segons</div>
    </div>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/temps.js"></script>

</body>     
</html>
```

Function works fine for all cases.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I fixed the error with your answer adr1Script.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> <span class="segons">00</span>
> ```

You made a typo. Class is not Id.

`document.getElementById('segons')` returns `null` because you don't have an element with that id at all, not because you are trying to read it too soon.

Answer (score 0):

**its can be found in ClassName** but you can't forget if you use to class name
all classes change of the same name

```js
    var all = $(".TestClass").map(function() {
        return this.innerHTML + " - js Test"; 
    }).get();

    $("p").html(all.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="TestClass">Test One</div>
    <div class="TestClass">Test Two</div>
    <div class="TestC">Test Two</div>


    <p></p>
```